# Shortcode WordPress with Query SQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, shortcode

I wanted to create a shortcode so I can "connect" my Coppermine gallery with my Wordpress, sadly I haven't been able to do it

I use this in my posts

```
[cpg album="533"]
```

To call this function

```
function cpg_shortcode( $attr ) {

    shortcode_atts(
  array(
    'album' => 1,
     ), $attr
    );
    return $album_id = $attr['album'];
    return '<script src="http://linklink.net/cpg/api-posts.php"></script>';
}
add_shortcode( 'cpg', 'cpg_shortcode' );
```

And this is the script file, which has no errors, it work perfectly fine, but I have to get the album id in it

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cpgq7_pictures` WHERE aid=$album_id ORDER BY ctime DESC LIMIT 0 , 3");

echo 'document.write(\'';
if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0){
    echo 'No hay fotos';
} else {
    echo '<h6>';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $domain = "http://linklink.net/cpg";
        $album_url = "$domain/thumbnails.php?album=$album_id#content";
        $album_img = "$domain/albums/".$row['filepath'].'thumb_'.$row['filename'];
        echo '<a href="'.$album_url.'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$album_img.'" alt="" /></a>';
    }
    echo '<a href="'.$album_url.'" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/4wmomUt.png" alt="" /></a></h6>';
}
echo '\');';
```

When I try to get the album id from the shortcode it doesn't work

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How do you try to pass the ID from the shortcode to the script file?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copy/pasted your shortcode and this line works as intended:

```
return $album_id = $attr['album'];
```

Returns the passed album parameter. If you want, you can use *extract* to have the id directly as $album available:

```
extract(shortcode_atts(
                array(
    'album' => 1,
                )
                , $attr));
```

now this looks pretty much wrong:

```
<script src="http://linklink.net/cpg/api-posts.php"></script>
```

is for javascript, it has nothing to do with php. just include the sql statement and output directly in your shortcode. changed the way of returning the data (ob_start/get_clean). also, like Dharman mentioned, check out how to execute sql statements safely.

```
function cpg_shortcode($attr) {

    extract(shortcode_atts(
                    array(
        'album' => 1,
                    )
                    , $attr));

    ob_start();

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cpgq7_pictures` WHERE aid=$album ORDER BY ctime DESC LIMIT 0 , 3");
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) {
        echo 'No hay fotos';
    } else {
        echo '<h6>';
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $domain = "http://linklink.net/cpg";
            $album_url = "$domain/thumbnails.php?album=$album#content";
            $album_img = "$domain/albums/" . $row['filepath'] . 'thumb_' . $row['filename'];
            echo '<a href="' . $album_url . '" target="_blank"><img src="' . $album_img . '" alt="" /></a>';
        }
        echo '<a href="' . $album_url . '" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/4wmomUt.png" alt="" /></a></h6>';
    }
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('cpg', 'cpg_shortcode');
```